# error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’)

Tags: c++

I am trying to build Tramonto fDFT package, but .cpp file got error like this:
error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}’ and ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}’)
stream <<  x1.leftshift(stream) << " " << x2.leftshift(stream)

Here is the code:

```
ostream& NOXLOCA::Tramonto::PTVector::leftshift(ostream& stream) const  
{
  stream << "{ ";
  stream <<  x1.leftshift(stream) << " " << x2.leftshift(stream)
         <<  " [ " << ptp << "] ";
  stream << "}";
  return stream; 
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const NOXLOCA::Tramonto::PTVector& v)
{
  return v.leftshift(stream);
}

void NOXLOCA::Tramonto::PTVector::print(std::ostream& stream) const
{
  stream << *this << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be trying to build an old version of the library. According to the project's github repository this [has been fixed](https://github.com/Tramonto/Tramonto/commit/cbfe44acfe849937e1865888f465dc14dc7bd09b#diff-eea47c2573e4ee72bf3457d61594540fbe936e9edbb5cabd0d6f295b0c4c2495R275) by commenting the offending lines four years ago.

Comment: @QinghuWang Please have a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Comments are not really meant for thank you messages.